# Trigger an alert when using Firebase observer and events

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, ios10

Working on an app that has two parts - Rider & Driver.  When the driver accepts the request, an alert is then sent to the rider that the request was accepted and driver is on the way.

Unable to trigger the alert to the rider.

RiderVC:

```
func driverAcceptedRequest(requestAccepted: Bool, driverName: String) {

    if !riderCancelledRequest {
        if requestAccepted {
            self.alertTheUser(title: "Ryde Accepted", message: "\(driverName) Has Accepted Your Ryde Request and will message you with details")
        } else {
            RydeHandler.Instance.cancelRyde()
            alertTheUser(title: "Ryde Cancelled", message: "\(driverName) Has Cancelled the Ryde Request")
        }
    }

    riderCancelledRequest = false
}
```

RydeHandler.swift:

```
// DRIVER ACCEPTED RYDE
    DataService.Instance.requestAcceptedRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.childAdded) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

        if let data = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
            if let name = data[Constants.NAME] as? String {
                if self.driver == "" {
                    self.driver = name
                    self.delegate?.driverAcceptedRequest(requestAccepted: true, driverName: self.driver)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Firebase database structure:

[image]

### Edit

ViewDidLoad in tableviewcontroller - list of requests:

```
ref.child("drivers").child("RideRequests").observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
        self.rideRequests.removeAll()
        for item in snapshot.children{
            self.rideRequests.append(item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
        }
        self.rideRequests.reverse()
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    })
```

Comment: did you set observe like `.Value` for any updation in data?

Comment: @JayeshThanki yes, I added an Edit to my post to show .observe